# How do I combine observable loop results to array in RxSwift?

Tags: rx-swift, reactive, rx-cocoa

I have a simple stream that has numbers. I want to do some mathematical operations and then collect results sequentially in an array. How can i do that ?

```
func test (number : Int) -> Observable<Int> {
        let obs2 = Observable<Int>.create { (obs) -> Disposable in
            obs.onNext(number + 10)
            return Disposables.create()
        }

        return obs2
    }

let obs = Observable.from([1,2,3,4]).flatMap { (item) -> Observable<Int> in
            self.test(number: item)
            }.map { (result) -> Int in
                return result
            }

//I want this: 
obs.subscribe(onNext : {[Int] in 
     ...
     ...
}
```

I can't combine every int to an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let arrayObservable = obs.reduce([]) { acc, element in acc + [element] }
```

Reduce will start with an empty array and will append each element of the stream to the array. It will then emit only one `.next` event, after the source `obs` completes, with the result of the accumulation.

---

Another option would be to use the [`buffer`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/65efb404c80fe1b23108c8fbb57d05b615e21c93/RxSwift/Observables/Buffer.swift#L23) operator. But keep in mind that the resulting array will only contain up to a certain number of elements and that it'll also emit every `timeSpan`, even if source did not emit any item.